# How can I add conditional binary variable to GUROBI

Tags: mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics, gurobi

I am working on mathematical modeling using Gurobi as a solver and python as an interface. In my model, I would like to create a binary variable but the variable is allowed to take a value of 1 if **a>=1** else 0 where a is another decision variable in the model.

the binary variable should look like this as follows in the picture:-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, you want to model the implications:

```
  x>=1 => y=1
  x=0  => y=0
  x >= 0 (non-negative variable)
  y ∈ {0,1}  (binary variable)
```

There are different ways to do this.

Note that we can invert the implications:

```
  y=0 => x=0
  y=1 => x>=1
```

**indicator constraints**

```
  y=0 => x=0
  y=1 => x>=1
```

can be directly implemented as indicator constraints. See https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html.

**Big-M approach**

```
  x <= M*y   (this will do y=0 => x=0)
  x >= y     (this will do y=1 => x>=1)
```

Here the constant M is an upper bound on x. If M is very large, it is better to use indicator constraints.